# Creating a Balancing Class to Balance Weights

Tags: objective-c

First of all I must admit that it is my assignment. But I am not asking anyone to solve it but I am working hard to solve it and need help with my algorithm.

I have an array of weights that is assigned to leftSide and rightSide of a scale. I need to balance the weights in right side and left side using the weights in the array.

I have the following code but it does not cover all the situations:

```
-(BOOL) isBalanced
{
    _weights = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@3,@4,@2,@1,@5,@6,@4]];

    self.leftSide =  [[_weights objectAtIndex:arc4random() % 7] integerValue]; // random weight
    self.rightSide = [[_weights objectAtIndex:arc4random() % 7] integerValue]; // random weight

    if(self.leftSide == self.rightSide) return YES; // already balanced

    if(self.leftSide > self.rightSide)
    {
        // add weights on right side
        int difference = self.leftSide - self.rightSide;
        int index = [_weights indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:difference]];
        self.rightSide += [[_weights objectAtIndex:index] integerValue];
         NSLog(@"%d",index);
    }
    else
    {
        int difference = self.rightSide - self.leftSide;
        int index = [_weights indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:difference]];
        self.leftSide += [[_weights objectAtIndex:index] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"%d",index);
    }

    return self.leftSide == self.rightSide;
}
```

UPDATE:

To simplify! I have a number 6 and now I need to search inside an array of ints if any of the numbers can be added together to get 6. Example:

```
1,2,3,5,4
```

In the above array I can take 1+2+3 which makes 6. I can also take 4+2 which is 6. The question is how do I find those individual numbers that can sum up to the number 6.

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Comment: Please see my update at the end of my question.